# Как переключить уведомления о смене пароля на другую почту?

Tags: php, wordpress

При смене пароля на почту админа приходит уведомление о смене пароля.
Подскажите, как сделать чтобы эти уведомления админу приходили на другую дополнительную почту, чтобы не засорять спамом основную почту?
Подойдут плагины если есть подходящие, или посоветуйте, где посмотреть на похожий код?

Comment: Могу посоветовать хук wp_mail, но я думаю есть еще какой-то, который немного выше и более в нужном месте

Comment: @Krya а как определить в wp_mail смену пароля?

Comment: Как вариант по subject

Comment: Можно изменить тайтл retrieve_password_title и сообщение retrieve_password_message, а вот именно емейл нельзя сменить

Comment: @Krya почему же нельзя, когда можно )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте примерно такой фильтр в `functions.php` темы:

```
/**
 * Modify $args of wp_mail.
 * Send changed password notification to another email.
 *
 * @param array $args Arguments.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function wp_mail_filter( $args ) {
    if ( false !== mb_strpos( 'Password Changed', $args['subject'] ) ) {
        $args['to'] = 'myemail@cool.org';
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_mail_filter' );
```

В теме сообщения может быть другая строка, если сайт не на английском. Замените 'Password Changed' на нужный текст, ну и подставьте свой email.

Comment: Ну такое... я думал ты реально крутое решение предложишь)

Comment: Чем тебе не решение? ) Прекрасно опровергает твой комментарий к вопросу ))

Comment: Прочитай комменты выше я написал тоже самое. Но хотел найти более изящное решение, которое не нашел

Comment: @Krya Читаю: "Можно изменить тайтл retrieve_password_title и сообщение retrieve_password_message, а вот именно емейл нельзя сменить". И показываю, как можно сменить email.

Comment: @KAGG Design, всё работает, благодарю, да получается Krya предложил такое же решение